# How to add Git nature to my project?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I cloned master branch into the directory

`\home\David\git\Example`

and then I went into the eclipse and imported this project and when i did that it imported the project to the directory

`\home\David\workspace\Example`

Now the problem is when I right click on the project in eclipse and select properties, I don't see `git` nature for this..

The below screenshot is on my office laptop

[image]

I have Egit plugin installed and I would like to be able to commit and push from eclipse..

Because the git nature is missing for the project, I cannot do that.

How do I add Git nature for the project?

Comment: then how do i get that project to show up on the project explorer window?

Comment: Import project in eclipse but do not copy it to workspace folder.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but it does not give that option..It is just directly importing into my workspace

Comment: There is a checkbox `Copy projects into workspace` in Import projects.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for someone who imported a project, for example, as a maven project and not as a git repository:

Right now, the fastest way to add git nature to your eclipse project is to right click to your project > team > share project

you should see your repo listed. Just click ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you previously had subversion (svn) enablee on the repository and you changed to git in-place, you need to disconnect first (Project>Team>Disconnect).
Then you can enable git in Eclipse using the method proposed by @mattia: Project>Team>Share Project.